# Trying to understand "undefined" warning in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This appears in my browser console:

> [Vue warn]: Error when evaluating expression "permissions.edit": TypeError: Cannot read property 'edit' of undefined (found in component: <heading>)

Related code:

```
{{ permissions | json }}
<a class="button" v-on:click="toggleEditMode" v-if="permissions.edit">{{ editMode ? 'Save' : 'Edit' }}</a>
```

Results in:

[image: Screenshot]

Permissions is obviously not undefined. What's going on? To make matters more confusing, if I pass a literal object to the component (`:permissions="{edit: true}"`), the warning goes away, but the json output from `{{ permissions | json }}` looks exactly the same.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you somehow added the `edit` property in a way that Vue did not notice it. (the json filter doesn't care for reactivity, so it does not matter there ) When and how are you creating / filling the permissions object? Do you change it somewhere, in a `ready()`  hook or something? Did you define the `permissions` object in the components `data` with the `edit` property already in place? These are relevant infos we need.

Comment: It's a server response from vue-resource, created in the `created()` method of my ViewModel. It's assigned to the ViewModel with `this.$set`, and passed as a prop in my template.

Comment: There we go. The APi call with vue-resource is async, meaning Vue does not wait for it to finish, but instead continues to compile the template, which happens much faster than the API call. so when Vue evaluates `permissions.edit`, it has not yet been set, as the API call is still going on in the background. As soon as that call has finished, `permissions` gets set properly and your template works as expectd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As discussed in the comments to your post, it's due to the async API call yo do in `created()` to get the permissions object initially.

I suggest you use something like https://github.com/vuejs/vue-async-data. It allows you to get data asynchronously (e.g. with vue-resource) and gives you a way to hide components content [until loading the data has finished](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-async-data#loading-state).

Though you can easily simulate this on your own:

```
data: function () {
  return { loaded: false, permissions: {} }
},
created() {
  return this.$http(...).then(function (result) {
    this.permissions = result.data.permissions // or however your data is
    this.loaded = true
  })
}
```

and in the template, use `v-if="loaded"` on a wrapping div to hide the content until permissions are actually loaded.

Comment: This is what I needed, still trying to wrap my head around two-way binding. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is because `permissions` is not Vue `path` object. Once you pass it as prop it will become one, and you will be able to reference it like that. Could you provide full code for your component for further explanation?